# Multiprocessing Python start processes time-displaced

Tags: python, multiprocessing

```
p = Pool(2)  
p.map(start_simulation, test_devices)
```

Like in the above code, i want to start two workers with the start_simulation function, but is there any way to delay this by a time interval? For example:

```
worker1@start_simulation  
wait 5 minutes  
worker2@start_simulation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be easier for you to implement `multiprocessing.Process`

```
import multiprocessing
import time

class Simulator(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, test_devices):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.test_devices = test_devices
    def run(self):
        start_simulation(self.test_devices)

workers = [Simulator(test_devices), Simulator(test_devices)]
workers[0].start()
time.sleep(300)
workers[1].start()

for i in workers:
    i.join()
```